# Force line break after nth element in flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have following code (simplified):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child-33 {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child-50 {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-33">1. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">3. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
</div>
```

the container is set to display flex. each child has flex grow set to 1.

I want every child to have 33% width but I want to break after the first child. The first line should only contain the first element (but with 33% width).The second line should contain 2+3+4. child.

I also have some rows where elements should have 50% width.

I cannot set the first child to 100% width or flex-basis because then every content is scaled to the full width and the div has a border which should not be full width.

Any suggestions? Maybe with :before or :after pseudo elements?

Comment: have you tried with a pseudo-element as you thought about it? What wasn't working as expected with that approach?

Comment: Pseudo elements will hardly work here, because those render as children _inside_ the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine building it something like this, using `.cell` elements to create the layout including empty cells as padding, and then stretching the cell content across the available width.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container * {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.cell {
  flex: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.content {
  flex: auto;
  margin: 2px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 2px outset #ccc8;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.c-2 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.c-3 {
  width: 50%;
}
.c-6 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell c-2"><div class="content">1. Row</div></div>
  <div class="cell c-2"></div>
  <div class="cell c-2"></div>
  <div class="cell c-2"><div class="content">2. Row<br>...<br>...</div></div>
  <div class="cell c-2"><div class="content">2. Row</div></div>
  <div class="cell c-6"><div class="content">3. Row</div></div>
  <div class="cell c-3"><div class="content">4. Row</div></div>
  <div class="cell c-3"><div class="content">4. Row</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i can't edit the html and wrap the content in a div. its an online tool where i just can add custom css

Comment: @warch should've probably said so in your question.

Comment: Sorry, but thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can't edit the html, here's an alternative version using targeted margins to force line breaks.

```css
.container {
  --border-spacing-x: 2px;
  --border-spacing-y: 1px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container > * {
  flex: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
.container > :first-child,
.container > :nth-child(5) {
  margin-right: 50%;
}

.child-33 {
  width: 33.33%;
  /* or, if you want some spacing */
  margin: var(--border-spacing-y) var(--border-spacing-x);
  width: calc(33.33% - 2 * var(--border-spacing-x));
}
.child-50 {
  width: 50%;
  /* or */
  margin: var(--border-spacing-y) var(--border-spacing-x);
  width: calc(50% - 2 * var(--border-spacing-x));
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child-33">1. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">3. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
  <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create like this but on first child width will be 100%, if you need to only 30% you can add width inside of first item child or you need to manage this on table.**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child-33 {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 33.33%;
  flex-basis: 33.33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child-50 {
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 50%;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child-100 {
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid;
    width: 33%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="child-100">1. Row</div>
        <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
        <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
        <div class="child-33">2. Row</div>
        <div class="child-100">3. Row</div>
        <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
        <div class="child-50">4. Row</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: The 1 and 3 row should not be full width.